# How to manage software updates from a central location?

Tags: linux, update

We have a number of servers: some of them have are containers over openVZ and some of them are full virtual machines. All of the servers are Linux systems only. The servers are running different software with some overlap across machines (e.g Apache). I am looking for the following answers:

a) Since these servers are running a large number of different software, we need a software solution where we provide a list of software and it automatically checks if an update is available or not.

b) A software solution to centrally update all of these different software across servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) with [Razor](https://puppetlabs.com/solutions/next-generation-provisioning/) could be a solution here.

Community are quite big, so you won't lack documentation or blog post to give you great starting points.